# Layout Objects positions difference when inflated

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have created an android activity that contains three tabs using tablayout and pager adapter. every tab has its Java file and (its layout in res/Layout folder).

the first tap has no problem while the problem appears in the second and the 3rd tab.

there is a difference between the layout xml design in android studio and when it is inflated on the emulator or real device.

the objects aren't in its correct positions and shifted horizontally and vertically! what is the problem causing this?

Android Studio Pic: (Spinners are in the correct position)

[image]

Emulator PIC: (Spinners are in incorrect positions)

[image]

Tab 3 Layout Design Example:

```
<RelativeLayout>
   <ScrollView>
      <RelativeLayout>
         <TextView>
         <TextView>
         <Spinner>
         <Spinner>
      </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

there are so many textviews and everyone has a spinner in front of it. and the problem appears in the spinners position, they are shifted up.

Tab 3 Java file:

```
public class DCO_New_Report extends Fragment{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.dco_new_report, container, false);
}
}
```

Main Activity Java:

```
public class DCODatabase extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dcodatabase);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.DCODatabaseToolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    assert toolbar != null;
    toolbar.setLogo(R.drawable.dco1);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab);
    assert tabLayout != null;
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("General Reports"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Report Display"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("New Report"));

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    assert viewPager != null;
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()  {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}


}
```

Main Activity XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="esmviewer.myandroid.com.esmviewer.DCODatabase">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/DCODatabaseToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DCODatabaseToolbar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tab"/>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Pager Adapter Java File:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int mNumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = mNumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            DCOGeneralReports tab1 = new DCOGeneralReports();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            DCOReportDisplay tab2 = new DCOReportDisplay();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            DCO_New_Report tab3 = new DCO_New_Report();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

Comment: If the only problem is in xml, please post only that file. Plus posting pictures that depict what you want and what result you are getting will help in solving the problem.

Comment: I added the pictures, I posted the XML files as I am not sure if they have a relation with the problem or not.

Comment: The best way would be to assign a pair of TextView and Spinner to a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation. Use weights to fix each view in its proper place and then try again. It might work.

Comment: LinearLayout Pairs worked fine :) thanks

Comment: Please mark my post as the answer if it helped.

Comment: how is that? your comment only has two flags to like or to flag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row, make a `LinearLayout` with `orientation` set to `horizontal`.

Then add a `TextView` and a `Spinner` to it with proper weights and it should work.

Hope this hepls :)